# How Do I change UITableViewCell Colour According to Array in Same Section Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have Two Array of Int In which the Index Number is Stored and I want that IndexPath.row cell Background Colour Should Change accordingly.

```
let   redCell     = ["0","1","4"]
let   greenCell   = ["2","3"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var  cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playQuizTableViewCell") as? playQuizTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == redCell {
        cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    } else if indexPath.row == greenCell{
        cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

I want to change cell colour of indexPath.row which is matching inside the array.

Please Guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make your arrays into arrays of `Int` instead of `String`.

```
let redCell = [0, 1, 4]
let greenCell = [2, 3]
```

Now update your `cellForRowAt` to check if `indexPath.row` is in a given array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playQuizTableViewCell") as! playQuizTableViewCell

    if redCell.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .red
    } else if greenCell.contains(indexPath.row) {
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .green
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .black
    }
}
```